# modrewrite doesnt load my css and images

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've a rewrite rule on my website. It converts this links:

http://www.qblza.com.br/anuncio_detalhes.php?ida=232&title=samsung-duos-camera-2-mp-redes-sociais-2-chips-bluetooth.html

Into this:

http://www.qblza.com.br/232/samsung-duos-camera-2-mp-redes-sociais-2-chips-bluetooth.html

Here's the rewrite rule I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /anuncio_detalhes.php?ida=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on a rewrite url, the site doesn't load any css and images...it just loads the text...I've no idea why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your stylesheet, images, and if you have javascript sources. Type "/" before the location.

Images:

`<img src="/file/to/path/image.jpg" />`

Stylesheet:

```
<link ref="stylesheet" href="/file/to/path/style.css" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="/file/to/path/javascript.js" />
```

Comment: This one really worked, can you just explain why I needed to include the / ?

Comment: It brings it to the root of the directory.

Right now if you don't do this, it tries to grab the images/css to:
http://www.qblza.com.br/232/file/to/path/style.css instead of http://www.qblza.com.br/file/to/path/style.css

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using relative paths for your static resources.
So when loading a rewrite-url the browser sees this in head:

```
<link id="menu-color" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu-gray.css">
```

and tries to load

http://www.qblza.com.br/232/samsung-duos-camera-2-mp-redes-sociais-2-chips-bluetooth.html/css/menu-gray.css

Solution 1: use absolute paths for loading your static resources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/menu-gray.css" />
```

So your browser will definitly follow the path from domain-root

Solution 2: use the base-tag

```
<base href="http://your-domain.com" />
```

With this you tell the browser which root to use when following paths (also images and the like)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html, I would say that the most likely problem is the url of the images and css. You need to use absolute urls (relative to the site root) when you rewrite your urls like you do.